# Is there any mathematical terminology to denote this operation? v(v^T)

Tags: linear-algebra

$vv^T$ is the vector multiplication of the same vector v, and its transposed vector $v^T$. This kind of multiplication is found in my study of computer vision frequently to make some projection matrices. Is there any specific terminology to denote such operation where 'a vector' is spanned to make a matrix of rank-1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called an **outer product**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product

Comment: The result of outer-product operation was another *vector* which is orthogonal to the original operands back to high school.

 Now I see that the operation in question being called outer-product also defines a *matrix*... referring to the Wikipedia, which actually I asked.

 Both of them are outer products. This can give an orthogonal vector, and also can define a Matrix that I am dealing. Do you catch why I am confused?